# solidity doubt error unknown

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, contract-deployment, code

ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function definition.
--> contracts/college.sol:104:1:
|
104 | }
| ^

Comment: This is not the case for you, but I'm going to leave this solution here for someone who may need this. I got this error when I forgot the semicolon ';' at the end of the first line pragma solidity ^0.4.25;. So be sure to check that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case for you, but I'm going to leave this solution here for someone who may need this. I got this error when I forgot the semicolon ';' at the end of the first line pragma solidity ^0.4.25;. So be sure to check that.